# How to restrict this function from execution in android? Please help

Tags: android

This code is present in one of this activity. I want to restrict addJoke() function from executing if the String variable new_joke is null, has no text or contains just spaces.
Here is code

```
protected void initAddJokeListeners() {
    // TODO
    m_vwJokeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
    //Implement code to add a new joke here...
            String new_joke=m_vwJokeEditText.getText().toString();
            if(new_joke!=null&&new_joke!=""&&new_joke!=" ")
            {
                addJoke(new_joke);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I don't know why addJoke() function is getting executed even I don't enter any text in EditText field. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you must do the String comparison with String's `.equals()`, so:

```
protected void initAddJokeListeners() {
    // TODO
    m_vwJokeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Implement code to add a new joke here...
            String new_joke = m_vwJokeEditText.getText().toString().trim();
            if(!new_joke.equals("")) {
                addJoke(new_joke);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Just a little refractor: `String new_joke=m_vwJokeEditText.getText().toString().trim();
if (new_joke != null && !new_joke.equals("")).....`

Comment: right @Francesco, I updated my answer (at first I just changed the .equals() thing that was the point of the question...)

Comment: @maid: Note it makes no sense to compare to " " after trimming. Nor comparing to null.

Comment: So now the second checks could be safely removed  ("&& !new_joke.equals(" ")") ;)

Comment: Right again, thanks @Tomas and @Francesco. Initially I rewritted the original code only fixing the main error, not optimizing it... ;)

Comment: but can I know why my code didn't work? and why addJoke() got executed each time?

Comment: because with != you are checking if the references are distinct (if the new_joke and "" 'pointed' to different places in memory) and that is always true, so it was always entering the if. However with !.equals() you check if the value is distinct. Basically, you must ALWAYS use equals() method when comparing strings

Comment: Got it Maid450...Moreover Objects are always compared using .equals and String is a class, Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
if (new_joke != null && !new_joke.trim().equals(""))
```

although in this case, you can leave the `new_joke == null` as that will never happen.

This is because with `new_joke == ""` you create a new empty string object and check whether that object is the same object as `new_joke` which is not the case.